# Differentiability of $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{x}{2+|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to check for any $x_0$ in its domain, whether this function is differentiable or not.

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{x}{2+|x|}$

For $x_0=0$ is $\frac{x}{2+|x|}= \frac{0}{2+|0|} \Rightarrow f$ is in $x_0=0$ not differentiable.

For $x>0$ is $f(x) = \frac{x}{2+x}$, for $x<0$  is $f(x) = \frac{x}{2-x}$ and since the Sum rule in differentiation and Quotient rule has already been proofed, $f(x)$ is as composition of differentiable functions differentiable.

Comment: How did you deduce $\;f\;$ is not differentiable at zero, again?

Comment: Take a closer look at $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: And consider the limit proper.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\color{#00f}{\large\totald{}{x}\pars{x \over 2 + \verts{x}}}
={1\times\pars{2 + \verts{x}} - \bracks{0 + \sgn\pars{x}}x\over \pars{2 + \verts{x}}^{2}}
={2 + \verts{x} - \verts{x}\over \pars{2 + \verts{x}}^{2}}
=\color{#00f}{\large{2 \over \pars{2 + \verts{x}}^{2}}} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\;\frac1{2+|x|}=\frac12\;\ldots$$